# DLNA - connect tv to router

Tags: router, tv, dlna

I have a tv which supports DLNA and I'd like to connect it to my PC so I could stream movies to it. However, I can't use a cable because the PC and it's router are too faraway. 
Therefore, I was thinking of getting the tv its own router, but I don't understand how to configure the routers to talk to each other.

Is it even possible?

Comment: What TV do you have?

Comment: James, I've got a 42 inch LG ls460y.
Does it somehow make my life easier with this DLNA stuff?

Comment: By saying "too far away", does that mean more than 100 meters? Or you just don't have a way to connect because of physical obstructions?

Comment: No, it's not that far away, I just don't want (and can't) that network cable running on the walls. That's why I thought that connecting the TV to my PC with wireless could be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [a switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=4%20port%20ethernet%20switch) to extend the network to your TV.

If you must use another router (you have one laying around), set it up in bridge mode (turn off routing/dhcp services) and just use the ethernet switch ports (ignore the gateway port).

Comment: I second the notion on using bridged mode.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you please elaborate? Where exactly do I place the switch?